# ISPCONFIG SSH/FTP User has the wrong path

Tags: apache, ispconfig

For some reasons, my ispconfig setup when I create a new FTP or SSH user, add /home/USER at the end of the path, like this:

/var/www/clients/client1/web12/home/user

Instead of just

/var/www/clients/client1/web12/

Someone has an idea?
Thanks

Comment: Why would you want all of your users to share a single home directory?

Comment: Actually it's not the point. /var/www/clients/client1/web12/home/user just doesn't exist. I want every user stays in his own website.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was used to work with it another way, but looks like the other sysadmin who worked on it had installed it badly. Now all fine. Thanks

Comment: How did you fix it then?